# Issue with understanding keystore and ssl

Tags: java, android, ssl, encryption

These are the facts:

I have a **client(android)-server(java - Ubuntu 14.04)-program** with which I **transmit my gps-data** from my smartphone every 5 minutes to the server saving it into a mysql-database.

My problem is that I do not want to transmit my GPS data plain. So I want to use SSL, to verify the client(my smartphone) to the server(making it impossible for someone else to connect to the server - no handshake) and of course to encrypt. 
My main issue is about understanding the keystore, truststore process.

With

> keytool.exe -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -alias -serverKey
>   -keystore serverKeystore.jks -validity 1095

I am creating a new keystore (if not existing) named serverKeystore.jks. This keystore includes the private key and the public key wrapped by the certificate.
I can export the certificate with

> -keytool.exe -export -alias serverKey -keystore serverKeystore.jks -file server.cer

So based on [this](http://notetipsblog.com/NoteTipsBlog/articles/java/security/ssl_socket_client_server_1.html) tutorial he now creates a clientkeystore:

> keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias clientKey -keystore
>   clientkeystore.jks -validity 999 -keysize 2048

and I export the client.cer the same way like I did with the server before.

Now he adds the server.cer to the clients-keystore and the clients.cer to the servers-keystore. But now serverKeystore and clientKeystore have created a different private/public key-pair. The server is now aware of the clients public key and the client is now aware of the servers public key. **That way the client can encrypt the plaintext with the public key of the server and the server can then decrypt it with his private key. Is this correct?**
If so where is the truststore? Is the truststore the server-keystore storing the client.cer and that way trusting this client and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now he adds the server.cer to the clients-keystore and the clients.cer to the server's keystore.

Wrong here. You should add the exported certificate to a *truststore* in each case. Export from server keystore to client truststore, client keystore to server truststore.

> That way the client can encrypt the plaintext with the public key of the server and the server can then decrypt it with his private key. Is this correct?

It's correct in theory but it isn't used that way. SSL negotiates a symmetric session key. The certificates and their keys are only used for authentication, not for encryption.

> If so where is the truststore?

See above.

Comment: Thank you. But what are the next steps if I got both truststores with one containing the server.cer and the other the client.cer. How do I combine them with my server-program and my client program being able to establish a secure connection?  I am not talking about implementing a SSLServerSocketFactory and creating an SSLServerSocket on the Server-Side. That is clear to me, but how to bring the two truststores in game?

Comment: You configure them as shown in the JSSE Reference Guide.

Comment: you don't say ! ;) The problem is that I do not understand that guide... I was hoping for a link to a small tutorial or a fast explanation because it is hard for me to understand this topic.